# Calculating zoomToSpan() degrees based on min/max lat/lng to be in the mapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, zooming

I have a cluster of items on an overlay in a mapView.
I know where the top/bottom/left/right most objects are.
I want to use the zoomToSpan() method to zoom onto that area.

What is the proper way to calculate the lat/lng degrees for this method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found someone else posting a good solution to this problem here:
http://www.anddev.org/zoom_and_span_on_a_cluster_of_points-t464.html

Good luck!

Comment: They were missing Math.abs on the calculations ... now it works

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked before, and there's an excellent answer, with code, here:

[Android MapView -setting zoom automatically until all ItemizedOverlay's are visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241487/android-mapview-setting-zoom-automatically-until-all-itemizedoverlays-are-visi)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to just use something like this:

```
mapController.zoomToSpan(overlay.getLatSpanE6(), overlay.getLonSpanE6());
```

Comment: Those methods probably did not exist at the time of this question