# Setting zoom level automatically in Google map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi
I am using Google map in Android.where I am drawing a line between two GeoPoints.I need set the zoom level dynamically as the distance between two points increases or decreases.

Waiting for your reply

Comment: i am not familiar google maps in android but in JavaScript version if you use LatLngBounds to contain your points, then you can use `map.fitBounds(bounds:LatLngBounds);` and it'll automatically adjust your view based on the LatLngBounds points.

Comment: Here a great answer by [Reno](http://stackoverflow.com/users/68805/reno):
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5242149/1839565

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`zoomToSpan()`](http://goo.gl/qE8T8) on `MapController`. Compute the span based on the distances between your points. If your points are not centered, either take that into account (by increasing the desired span) or recenter the map.

Answer (score 3):

I've found similar solution. You can use `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds bounds, int padding)`

Here is an example:

```
Builder boundsBuilder = LatLngBounds.builder();
ArrayList<LatLng> decodedPoints = (ArrayList<LatLng>) PolyUtil.decode(step);
for (LatLng point : decodedPoints) {
    boundsBuilder.include(point);
}
LatLngBounds bounds = boundsBuilder.build();
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10);
map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
```