# Drawing a line/path on Google Maps and see the complete path line in visible area

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a path they draw routes path on the mapview and I search the way for show the complete path with the best zoom level for the longer of the path.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to find a method for setting the zoom as far in as it can go while still displaying your entire path? Like computing the bounding rectangle for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you iterate through the points in your path and find the maximum longitudes and latitudes, (that is, the farthest points north, south, east, and west), you'll have the bounding rectangle for your path (that is, the smallest rectangle that can contain your path).

From there, you can find the center of your rectangle. Get the MapController for your MapView (using MapView.getController()) and use MapController.setCenter() to set the map's center to the center of the rectangle.

Finally, compute the latitude span and longitude span (the north-south size of your rectangle and the east-west size of your rectangle) and pass those into MapController.zoomToSpan().

Answer (score 0):

I know this question had been asked a while back, but if anyone else bumps into the same issue try this answer:

`int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE; int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE; int minLon = Integer.MAX_VALUE; int maxLon = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  for (GeoPoint item : items)  {         int lat = item.getLatitudeE6();       int lon = item.getLongitudeE6();        maxLat = Math.max(lat, maxLat);       minLat = Math.min(lat, minLat);       maxLon = Math.max(lon, maxLon);       minLon = Math.min(lon, minLon);  }  mapController.zoomToSpan(Math.abs(maxLat - minLat), Math.abs(maxLon - minLon)); mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint( (maxLat + minLat)/2,  (maxLon + minLon)/2 ));`

It was answered earlier at [this StackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241487/android-mapview-setting-zoom-automatically-until-all-itemizedoverlays-are-visib/5242149#5242149)

Hope it helps someone.