# Android Mapview zoomout after zoomToSpan crashes my app

Tags: android, android-mapview

here's my code:

```
MapController cont = map.getController();
GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat)/2,(maxLon+ minLon)/2 );
cont.zoomToSpan((maxLat- minLat),(maxLon- minLon));
cont.setCenter(center);
cont.zoomOut(); // this cause my app to crash
```

I need the 'cont.zoomOut();' because android's zoomToSpan is ALMOST good enough . i still need to  zoom out (one level up)  in order to make all my overlays/geopoints etc. visible .

so where do i zoomOut after zoomToSpan ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right solution is using some padding when using zoomToSpan method:
[Android MapView -setting zoom automatically until all ItemizedOverlay's are visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5242149/414969)